# Getting the line count of a file hosted on S3

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chunking

We allow people to upload files to S3, and then we display a line count of how many lines are in that file. We do this by running a background process (DelayedJob) that fetches the file from S3 and then counts the number of newlines in the document. In general, this works pretty well.

Here is the code that does the work:

```
  def self.line_count_from_s3(options={})

    options = { :key => options } if options.is_a?(String)

    line_count = 0

    unless options[:key]
      raise ArgumentError, 'A valid S3 key is required.'
    end

    s3 = AWS::S3.new
    file = s3.buckets[ENV['S3_BUCKET']].objects[options[:key]]

    unless file.exists?
      raise IOError, 'Unable to load that import from S3. Key does not exist.'
    end

    # Stream download chunks of the file instead of loading it all into memory
    file.read do |chunk|
      # Normalize line endings
      chunk.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")
      line_count += chunk.scan("\n").count
    end
    # Don't count the empty newline (assumes there is one)
    line_count -= 1 if line_count > 0

    line_count
  end
```

For some reason, a few files are turning up with completely wrong line counts. For example, a file that has 10,000 lines is showing up with a line count of 40,000. This isn't consistent. Most files work just fine.

I'm trying to figure out if this could be caused by the way the S3 chunked reader works, or if something else is causing the issue. Any idea why the record counts would be wrong? Is there a better way to do this that I'm not aware of?

Comment: are all files of same format?

Comment: Right now they are all the same CSV format, however, that will change fairly soon. As for the file encoding, they are generally UTF8, win32 or ASCII files. We do the gsub(/\r\n?/, "\n") to normalize line endings in the file chunk before counting them.

Comment: Does the same file produce the same erroneous count all the time. Have you tried not mutating chunk in place ? It looks like net/http assumes that you won't modify this buffer, so that might be throwing things off.

Comment: I was trying to do same thing, by using AWS lambda, so whenever the file arrives, it will count the number of records, I was running shell command in python, and was getting the error "OSError: [Errno 7] Argument list too long". Did you find a way to do this without error.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know why you are initializing `line_count` to `0` and doing `+=`. You don't need it. And your counting routine would be simplified as:

```
file.read do |chunk|
  chunk.gsub!(/\r\n?/, "\n")
  line_count = chunk.count("\n")
end
```

Comment: We read the file in chunks instead of reading the whole file at once. I'm of the impression that each chunk only represents a portion of the file and that's why we add the line counts of each chunk together. Is that not right?

Comment: I see. But I don't see any routine that iterates over the chunks.

Comment: If you pass a block to S3Object.read, it automatically chunks the download: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/S3Object.html